# Limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{\sqrt{x}+5}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{\sqrt{x}+5}$$

I know that we can say that $5<<x$ so we can evaluate:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}=1$$

I have try some substitution like $t=\sqrt{x+5}$ but it did not work:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{\sqrt{x}+5}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-5}+5}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-5}+5}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{t^2-5}-5}{\sqrt{t^2-5}-5}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t\cdot (\sqrt{t^2-5}-5) }{t^2-5-25}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\frac{t\cdot (\sqrt{t^2-5}-5)}{t^2} }{1-\frac{30}{t^2}}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\frac{\cdot (\sqrt{t^2-5}-5)}{t} }{1-\frac{30}{t^2}}$$

Comment: You could divide both sides by $\sqrt{x}$ and obtain
$$
\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}}}{1+\frac{5}{\sqrt{x}}}
$$
and that should be pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{\sqrt x+5}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{\sqrt x}}{\frac{\sqrt x+5}{\sqrt x}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
{{\sqrt {x + 5} } \over {\sqrt x  + 5}} = {{\sqrt {x\left( {1 + 5/x} \right)} } \over {\sqrt x \left( {1 + 5/\sqrt x } \right)}}
 = {{\sqrt x \sqrt {\left( {1 + 5/x} \right)} } \over {\sqrt x \left( {1 + 5/\sqrt x } \right)}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a different approach, note that

$${\sqrt{x+5}\over\sqrt x+5}-1={\sqrt{x+5}-\sqrt x\over\sqrt x+5}-{5\over\sqrt x+5}={5\over(\sqrt x+5)(\sqrt{x+5}+\sqrt x)}-{5\over\sqrt x+5}\to0-0=0$$